# How to Move file in wordpress on plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to move file in  wordpress on plugin activation . i have written a code for this but it is not working .

```
function onactivation_install(){
    $src = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/sinetiks-schools/plugin_list.php';
    $dest = get_template_directory();
    $full_path = $dest.'/';
    $flag = wp_handle_upload($src,$full_path);
    var_dump($flag);    }
register_activation_hook( __FILE__,'onactivation_install' );
```

Comment: whats getting displayed on var_dump?

Comment: giving an error ,The plugin generated 67 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Comment: echo $flag['error']; it or even in var_dump it maybe showing the exact error what it is?

Comment: okay the comment the var_dump statement and activate it and then check in the dir it maybe successfully done

Comment: no, file is not uploaded in destination folder

Comment: then do one thing use update_option("check_error",$flag['error']); and activate it and go and check it in database table what it is generating

Comment: now i am getting array(1) { ["error"]=> string(24) "Invalid form submission." }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass this parameter

```
$flag = wp_handle_upload($src,array( 'test_form' => false ));
```

Comment: Where should be destination folder path

Comment: it will upload in uploads directory